# Using "et al." in maths papers

Tags: journals, mathematics, citation-style

In general, mathematics papers have [no first author](http://www.ams.org/profession/leaders/culture/CultureStatement04.pdf); instead, authors are listed alphabetically. Therefore, citing “Smith et al.” is at best misleading (it implies that Smith did all the work) and at worst insulting (Zelmanov never does any work!). Basically, all the authors are considered equal but citing “Smith et al.” messes this balance up.

The “et al.” style is made slightly more complex because it means that the “big shot” may come further down the list. For example, Zelmanov is the big name but the paper is Smith, Smythe and Zelmanov, cited as Smith et al. So you don’t realise that it’s a Zelmanov paper.

My question is:

> What should be done if a journal changes your citation of *Smith, Smythe and Zelmanov [10]* to *Smith et al. [10]*, especially when Zelmanov is the big name?

Is the answer simply to ask them to change it back to Smith, Smythe and Zelmanov? I think that changing the citation to “Zelmanov et al.” undermines the equality ethos even more — it is a slap in the face to Smith and Smythe, and anyway how do I not know that Smith won’t win a Fields medal himself one day?

I should say that before today I have never seen this in a maths paper.

---

Added 2018: This was resolved nicely. I send the copyediting team an email asking if every instance of "et al." could be changed back "especially on line 244 because "et al." here is just a single person!", and if not can I edit the certain bits to remove the names. So they removed each et al. and it appeared online a week later. No hassle (but lots of worry!).

Comment: They should either change it back to your original style, or if they refuse, just give the label [10]. There is no justification for elevating some authors over others.

Comment: Regarding your second paragraph: in fields with citation orders, big shots almost always come further down the list, since they are almost always the _last_ author.

Comment: I don't recall having seen math journals do this.  What journal is this?  Do all the other paper in the journal do this?

Comment: @Kimball It is a Springer journal. I searched about in Springer journals for a while and I found one other paper which did this (and then I immediately stopped searching). *However*, I saw no citations of >2 people before finding this example.

Comment: Not all Springer journals have the same formatting guidelines.  You should specifically look for papers in the journal you're publishing in.

Comment: @Kimball I did that too - I was mostly just side-stepping your question for fear of...something...

Comment: The best thing to do is to is first ask the editor nicely if they will change it back. If they will not, then insist more firmly that they allow you to rewrite the paragraph, at which point you can add the author names in the prose. The editors have a paper they are nearly ready to publish, and so they want to get it off their desk.  I have written a different answer on this subject here: http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/36731/16122

Comment: (revision of earlier comment) Actually, I just checked a recent Springer paper of mine (in _Math Z_), and I noticed they did this to my paper too. I'm sure I disliked this at the time, but then forgot it as there were plenty of things I was unhappy at with Springer's copyediting. Anyway, I guess this is the standard for Springer math, as WillieWong mentions in his answer.  After some thought, I think it may be worthwhile to pushback, as Veblen and Anonymous suggest.  If people keep combating this policy, they may consider changing it.

Comment: This is why I changed my last name to A'abanana.

Comment: @smci I've rolled back you edit as, although your new title asks a relevant question, this question isn't the question I am specifically asking.

Comment: I don't see why this is getting closed as opinion-based. This is quite about the culture of math publishing, and while we may have different opinions on things, we still can produce quality and objective answers.

Comment: Related: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/41759/how-to-cite-papers-where-the-names-are-sorted/41760#41760 You certainly cannot cite it as _Zelmanov et al._

Comment: @user1729 then please improve the title. It's unclear from the title that this is anything more than an arbitrary stylistic issue; you're asking if it's fair to alphabetically later-named authors and whether people infer contribution from order of appearance in the author-list, in particular for maths.

Comment: _So you don’t realise that it’s a Zelmanov paper._ — It's **not** a Zelmanov paper.  It's a Smith, Smythe, and Zelmanov paper!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Disagreeing with the other answers here, I advocate that you **argue with the publishers** and ask them to revert the citation style to what you originally wrote. I have personally succeeded in doing so in exactly the situation you describe.

Of course you should be polite, and only "argue" if the publishers refuse to accommodate an initial non-argumentative request. But do remember that the role of publishers is to take our golden eggs without payment and then sell them back to us at extortionate rates. As such, I think it is perfectly appropriate to put your preferences above those of the publishers. The publishers might refuse in the end, in which case you should just relent, but I don't think you lose anything by pushing an argument to such a refusal.

Typically, I have found journal copyediting staff to be accommodating and helpful when I have requested that they undo changes like this.

Comment: I upvoted. Though believe me that _arguing with your copy editor is not a good idea_. It's much better to explain why you want it. I know this, since I am a copy editor myself :-)

Answer (score 39):

While mathematics is not my area of specialization, I think that in your question you are making a general and IMHO *wrong assumption* about the importance of the name, appearing in the "et al." construction. Essentially, this construction is used only for the purposes of convenience (brevity for readability) and **not** for implying the *amount* or *importance* of work, performed by any of authors.

When people see the "et al." citation, I am pretty sure that decent scientists immediately refer to the *full citation* in a reference list in order to obtain **full** information on **all** authors of a paper in question. Therefore, I believe that the "problem" that you have described in your question is really an *artificial* one, which exists only in your imagination (due to the incorrect assumption, mentioned above).

Comment: This is not actually my reaction on reading a citation with "et al." in a math paper. My first reaction is "wow, that paper must have at least 5 or 6 authors for the author of this paper to have chosen this way of citing them".

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: [to be precise, 6](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2011/02/et-al-when-and-how.html) (at least if you or a journal follow an APA derived style).

Comment: @WillieWong I see. I was not actually aware that there was such a convention, it was just my own gut feeling.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Well, then all I can say is that your reaction reflects on secondary, less (if any) essential aspect. As I said, I believe that the main role of an "et al." construction is purely of convenience.

Comment: Several of the papers I've read in astronomy/astrophysics lately have not only used "First Author, et al." within the main text (and insofar as, unlike math, this is a First=Most Important field, that can be okay), but also in the bibliography (which also failed to provide any of the actual titles).  Bibliography entries will go like: "Zoccali, et al. ApJ 23 106-123, 2013" and that's it.  So looking to the bibliography for full information is precisely useless in some fields, as even if you can explain missing authors (these papers could have a dozen or more), why not even the title?

Comment: @WillieWong This convention of "6" is ***NOT FOLLOWED*** by most people. What APA considers right is, in my opinion, highly irrelevant.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy The primary goal of the bibliography is the contain the necessary information to identify the reference. Not to give credit to particular people.

Comment: @yo' to be honest, I couldn't care less about what you or the APA considers right. I don't even claim that the exactly convention of "6" is followed by many, to say nothing of most, people. My comment was very clear, and indisputable if you chose to follow the APA style guide. It is also meant to inject a bit of irrelevant and irreverent precision into the previous comment. So **chill out, dude**, and stop shouting at me.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy I agree this practice is bad but it is so easy now (and implemented in most html version of article) to look the complete info on the web that I don't see a real problem here.

Comment: @yo' I agree, but then is the point of the in text citation to get you to the bibliography entry so the reader can identify the reference?

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh There's research showing that in fields where alphabetical + 'et al' is used, people earlier in the alphabet get better jobs. That's not purely inconvenience.

Comment: @JessicaB That's interesting, even though I suspect that those people get better jobs not because of their position in the co-authors list, but rather because the are/were already more experienced, skilled or occupy higher position in academia hierarchy (e.g., PI), so the former is a consequence of the latter (i.e., reversed cause and effect). Nevertheless, I'm curious to see some of the research you mention, so I'd appreciate if you could share relevant links with me.

Answer (score 23):

Regarding your specific question, the answer is **leave it be** and don't argue.

1. Most journals follow some house style guide that has been set in stone for who knows how long. This is not a useful fight to have since you will invariably lose.
2. Many style guides offer something similar to what [the APA guide says](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2011/02/et-al-when-and-how.html), which is that for papers of N or fewer authors (for APA, N = 5), at the *first* instance of mentioning the paper the full author listing must be included; in the subsequent ones *et al.* is used. In pure mathematics papers with more than 4 or 5 authors are quite rare (enough that [people come up with team names](http://wiki.math.toronto.edu/DispersiveWiki/index.php/I-team) when that happens). So credit usually is given properly (at least at the beginning of the paper).

   *N.B.* since the OP [mentioned Springer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/47618/using-et-al-in-maths-papers/47623#comment109724_47618), I should note that the Springer MathPhys style which applies to most (all?) mathematics journals in the Springer catalog does *not* follow the same schema as the APA style guide. Experience suggests (since I cannot find it written down somewhere) that for 1 and 2 authors they always show all names, and for 3 and more authors they always abbreviate. My experience also shows however that if you write "the Smith-Smythe-Zeldanov construction [13]" they will not call you on it.
3. Whether Zelmanov is a big name should have absolutely nothing to do with it; for all you know a lot of the technical insights could have come from Smythe.
4. If you must show all three names, rewrite the sentence/paragraph so that the appearance of all three names is logical.

   > In 1989 Smythe [12] showed that all gadgets are widgets. This result was later generalized in his 1993 paper [11], written together with Smith and Zeldanov, which showed that in fact all weak-gadgets (hereon "wadgets") are also widgets.

   Of course this formulation puts the emphasis on Smythe, but if "credit" is so important to you you should have a good idea how to phrase things correctly.

Comment: Nice answer (+1). However, I have to note that your point on `N=5` per APA (and similar for other styles) is shaky, since the full `N` authors citation should be done only at the _initial_ occurrence. Thus, for _all subsequent_ citations, it boils down to "et al." all over again.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh: for giving credit, is it not enough to have the name appear at least once? I don't think that mentioning the same paper multiple times in my paper means I am giving it "multiples" of credit... // I edited slightly to give more emphasis to that fact you pointed out.

Comment: For giving credit there exist a _reference list_ with full listing of all authors (excluding edited volumes). However, my point is that a reader kind of "loses" track of proper credit for all subsequent citations, occurring in multiple different _contexts_ throughout the paper.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh: fair enough. If in-context credit is really important, there are ways to "write around" the house styles.

Comment: I disagree with "leave it be and don't argue", for the reasons laid out in the post "Et al is unethical" here: https://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2010/02/21/et-al-is-unethical/

Comment: @WillieWong: I agree. However, I'm not sure whether it makes sense and is feasible to "write around", if there are significantly many in-text citations throughout a paper - in that case, I'd say to just rely on the reference list and assume that readers will make efforts to consult it.

Comment: @Aleksandr Blekh: the challenge with the reference list is that, although it has enough information to look up the reference, the prose of the paper you are writing is what helps to establish the name that mathematicians use to refer to the results. So if everyone calls the theorem the "Smith et al theorem" then the other authors don't receive that credit at conferences, etc. I don't want to draw out the discussion, so I won't comment more on this thread, but I think this issue is worth keeping in mind. See also http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/36731/16122

Comment: @OswaldVeblen: Re: your 1st comment. I'm sorry, but I find the rationale _"many readers are never going to get around to looking at the other names"_ simply ridiculous. It is readers' **responsibility** to refer to the reference list to obtain full and proper credit. Otherwise, what is the purpose of a reference list? Re: your 2nd comment. I understand your point. However, a scientific artifact, such as a theorem (as opposed to a publication) is usually a product of one-two (max, three) people. Thus, IMHO it is easy to use a Smith-Golden-Circle notation in-text to avoid that problem.

Comment: @OswaldVeblen: the question specifically asked "Smith-Smythe-Zeldanov [10]" not "Smith-Smythe-Zeldanov Theorem [10]", so your second comment has a bit of strawman. Regardless, points 2 and 4 of my post already addressed the issues you raised, and gave essentially [the same suggestion as you did](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/47618/using-et-al-in-maths-papers/47623#comment109739_47618), except that I recognized (from experience) that on issues of house style copy editors will never budge, so you might as well just skip to the last step directly.

Answer (score 9):

While formally the author order is unimportant, our psychology does not obey such formal rules. In the situation described, after the passage of time we are likely to remember either "paper by Smith et al." or "paper by Zelmanov and someone else".

Existence of publisher's style is mostly irrelevant (at least in my part of mathematics). Practically all the new papers are on arXiv, and so few read the journal version. So, authors' decisions matter.

In my opinion, the real choice is between the following options:

- Inclusive, "Smith, Smythe, Zelmanov [25] showed"
- Simple, "in [25] it is shown".
- Verbose, "Smith, Smythe, Zelmanov [25], building on the previous work of Smythe [26], showed".

Comment: If few read the journal version, then perhaps we shouldn't care what the journal changes in copyediting? Since presumably the version on arXiv will be the one reflecting the author's choice.

Answer (score 7):

The term "et alii" (abbreviated "et al.") means "and coworkers" or "and collaborators". It implies no preference who did what. So go with the style as suggested -- it does not imply that you elevate one of the authors over the others, it just abbreviates the list of names.

Comment: "It implies no preference" -- unfortunately it does *suggest* one in ordinary English. If I wrote "John and others" instead of "John, Paul, George and Ringo" then you might wonder why I've chosen not to name the others. You can't conclude with certainty that it's because I think Lennon's the most important Beatle, but it's high on the list of possibilities. But this isn't ordinary English, it's a stylised citation formula, so in some sense it doesn't really matter what "et al" means. It might as well be simple truncation "John, Pa..."

Comment: The direct translation is "and others", not "and coworkers". Wolfgang Bangerth is correct in the meaning, however.

Answer (score 1):

How the paper is cited will have nothing to do with the author's impact factor, or any citation tracking number in existence -- only the fact that the paper was cited at all has meaning.  Tenure committees will not care whether you said et al. or listed the authors' names.  Authors will not care, because it really makes no difference.

It is a decision made by the style sheet of the journal you're publishing in.  If you don't care for the style, submit only to journals that reference by superscripted numbers in the text.

Comment: Nobody questions bibliometrics here, as far as I see :-) So you are right that it makes no difference for bibliometrics, but it may make a difference for "the real world" :)

Comment: Along with the Math field's decision (or consensus) to use alphabetical authorship, comes ramifications.  One would think that if the authors objected, they would rebel an place authorship in different order.  In any case, the revolution should come from the authors, who bought in by publishing the way they did.

Comment: You speak like a medical :) The point is that we, mathematicians, couldn't care less about the order in which we appear on papers. Rather than on stupid things like "credit of being first", we care about true cooperation :-)

Comment: @yo'  Couldn't agree more.  The point I'm inadequately trying to make is that this is a system set up by mathematicians for a reason, and going out of one's way to undo it with citation style is counter to those goals.

Answer (score -1):

One purpose of the way to shorten author lists is to allow finding the cited work when it is listed in a library catalog, which happens (primarily/only) by first author. Hence knowing the first author is essential in order to find the text - no matter how important whose contribution to the work in question is (a subjective question anyway). Granted, this kind of restriction comes from the time of cardboard catalogs, but the implied citing tradition still stands ...

Comment: Not sure how this addresses the question, seems to be more of a comment along the same topic. Am I missing something?

Comment: "..but the tradition still stands..." -- well, no, actually, not so much. An OPAC or bibliographic database will generally let you search by any of the listed authors. Librarianship is not stuck in technological limitations from thirty years ago.

Comment: @LindaJeanne The fact that H.-D. Ebbinghaus, H.Hermes, F. Hirzebruch, M. Koecher, K.Mainzer, A.Prestel, R. Remmert, "Zahlen" can be found by searching for works by Remmert does not contradict the fact that the tardition of *citing* the work as as *Ebbinghaus et al*. Likewise, it is inspired pre-Amazon logistics why bibliographic rules would prefer *Berlin; Heidelberg; New York; Tokyo* over *Springer*

Answer (score -1):

Sorry to contradict, but I have published Maths papers with a true, ordered (by contribution) authors list.  This may not always be the case, but this counterexample proves that the assumption that the authors list is always ordered by name only is wrong.

As for the `et al.` - this is just an abbrevation, not for selecting important authors.  As a general rule for citing (used in many journals), if there are more than 2 authors, you do not list all, just the first and then write `et al.` *in italics*.  Sometimes you would use this short citation style in the text, and list the complete author list in the references, like

```
This has been proven by Smith et al. back in 1975 [8].

[8] AJ Smith, T Southall, EK Forkner and UI Janeson, Why Squirrels cannot Fly, Nature 4(5), September 1975.
```

As someone who cites, please respect the order given (for whatever reason), do not change it!  This would just confuse people.

Comment: You make a good point about the order not always being alphabetical, and I had meant to write my original post to reflect this. I've edited it accordingly.

Comment: _I have published Maths papers with a true, ordered (by contribution) authors list_ — So have I.  We broke the ties alphabetically.  And we were all tied.

Comment: @JeffE You are proving my point.  Sometimes it works like this, sometimes like that.  It's all good.  I only said that it isn't always done the same way.