# Change of tense in paper by editor

Tags: writing

I received my paper back from the editor of a journal. They changed the present tense in the abstract in my paper into past tense. So they changed: "Something is shown/developed/proposed" into "Something was shown/developed/proposed". This seems quite off. I do not refer to things that happened or have been done in previous work, but things that are done in this paper. What would you advice me to do here? I understand that this is valid for the methods, but also for the abstract? Is this even correct?

Comment: Are you in a field, were writing “we show/develop/propose” is not the norm? Because in other fields writing in a passive voice like you did implies that you are talking about something others did.

Comment: The field is enginering. I am honestly not sure. Other papers in my field use also present tense. So I am quite confused by the sudden change. They also changed present into past tense in the introduction section (which sometimes state what will be done in this paper) and the methods sections, where I explain my experiment setup.

Comment: By "editor" do you mean "copy editor", or "handling editor"?

Comment: I mean the people at the journal taking care of correct english at the last step before publication.

Comment: This is not the hill to die on.

Comment: @Lemonbonbon Ok. In my experience, the people at this stage are not experts in the subject and so less familiar with subject specific nuances, like tense, unlike handling editors who *are* experts. (So you might want to specify this in your question.)

Comment: Hm, but if I say "In this paper, a model is proposed" in the introduction, it sounds odd to say instead "In this paper, a model was proposed". It is still a describtion of what I am doing IN THIS paper, not something that has been done.

Comment: I had a similar situation, at the same stage in publication, which I asked about [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/47618/1057); maybe you will find some of the answers there helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The confusion is due to your choice of passive voice. It is because passive voice does not explain *who* did something, and as a consequence one is left to wonder whether a sentence "It is shown..." refers to something *others* had previously done (past tense) or whether it is something *you* do in this paper.

If you had written "In this paper, we show..." it would all have been clear. Just use the opportunity to rewrite your abstract and purge all occurrences of the passive voice there (along with everywhere else in that paper, and while you're at it: from your life -- the use of passive voice in scientific writing is a cancer that needs to be eradicated!).

Comment: I completely disagree with the idea that the passive is always bad. Sometimes it is clearly better. Here is an example, by [Bill Walsh](https://www.theslot.com/passive.html): The active voice is overrated. Oops. I guess those who disagree would make that "People overrate the active voice."

Comment: Both "Something is shown" and "Something was shown" are in the passive voice, so I don't think this can be an explaination for why the editor changed things. My personal view is that the active voice is to be prefered, but not at all costs, sometimes the passive voice is justified. Actaully, I quite like the explaination here: https://clauswilke.com/blog/2015/12/19/dont-use-the-passive-voice/

Comment: @toby544 The fact that one can find counterexamples (and non-standard uses of passive voice that do seem to have a subject like in your case) does not negate the fact that using the passive voice is greatly detrimental to the readability of scientific articles in general.